# PHP file upload Status

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, upload

I'm working on a file uploading system with PHP/MySQL. When i upload a file i see a little box in the left lower corner of  that shows the status of the upload. So my question is, is there any way i can fetch that information and display it, with JavaScript? 
Here is my code: https://github.com/theadamlt/filehunt
The form is located in upload.php, witch has the action of uploadaction.php
When uploadaction.php is running i see the small status box that shows the percentage of the upload.
I would prefer not to change too much in my uploadaction.php

Thank you in advance
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) and it does this for you. Its very flexible so you can customize it however you like. Or you can use [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), a more detailed tutorial on how to do this with APC is available [here](http://www.haughin.com/2007/10/php-upload-progress-with-php-52-apc/).

Hope this helps.